# BC36645 error in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, overloading, building

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to develop a website using web forms and Visual Basic. My problem is the error BC36645 has occured, preventing me from building the solution. It is described as *"Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in method 'Public Shared Overloads Function FromResult(Of TResult)(result As TResult) As Task(Of TResult)' cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error."*

Which I understand the basic meaning of. However, it's stated to be in a file that I have not touched, it's autogenerated. The file is IdentityModels.vb located in the Models folder.

I got the same error in another project in the same solution, which I solved by deleting, re-creating the project and rebuilding. But this is not really a convenient way to solve the problem.

Does someone have the same problem, can explain what it is about, or even have a proper solution?

//Eva-Lotta

EDIT:

This is the contents of the file the error points to (with the error in "        Return Task.FromResult(GenerateUserIdentity(manager))":

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Security.Claims
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security

Public Class ApplicationUser
    Inherits IdentityUser

Public Function GenerateUserIdentity(manager As ApplicationUserManager) As 

    Dim userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(Me, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)

    Return userIdentity
End Function

Public Function GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager As ApplicationUserManager) 
    As Task(Of ClaimsIdentity)
        Return Task.FromResult(GenerateUserIdentity(manager))
End Function

End Class

Public Class ApplicationDbContext
Inherits IdentityDbContext(Of ApplicationUser)
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema:=False)
End Sub

Public Shared Function Create As ApplicationDbContext
    Return New ApplicationDbContext()
End Function
```

End Class

```
#Region "Helpers"
Public Class 
Public Const XsrfKey As String = "xsrfKey"

Public Const ProviderNameKey As String = "providerName"
Public Shared Function GetProviderNameFromRequest(request As HttpRequest) As String
    Return request.QueryString(ProviderNameKey)
End Function

Public Const CodeKey As String = "code"
Public Shared Function GetCodeFromRequest(request As HttpRequest) As String
    Return request.QueryString(CodeKey)
End Function

Public Const UserIdKey As String = "userId"
Public Shared Function GetUserIdFromRequest(request As HttpRequest) As String
    Return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(request.QueryString(UserIdKey))
End Function

Public Shared Function GetResetPasswordRedirectUrl(code As String, request As HttpRequest) As String
    Dim absoluteUri = "/Account/ResetPassword?" + CodeKey + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code)
    Return New Uri(request.Url, absoluteUri).AbsoluteUri.ToString()
End Function

Public Shared Function GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code As String, userId As String, request As HttpRequest) As String
    Dim absoluteUri = "/Account/Confirm?" + CodeKey + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code) + "&" + UserIdKey + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userId)
    Return New Uri(request.Url, absoluteUri).AbsoluteUri.ToString()
End Function

Private Shared Function IsLocalUrl(url As String) As Boolean
    Return Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(url) AndAlso ((url(0) = "/"c AndAlso (url.Length = 1 OrElse (url(1) <> "/"c AndAlso url(1) <> "\"c))) OrElse (url.Length > 1 AndAlso url(0) = "~"c AndAlso url(1) = "/"c))
End Function

Public Shared Sub RedirectToReturnUrl(returnUrl As String, response As HttpResponse)
    If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) AndAlso IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) Then
        response.Redirect(returnUrl)
    Else
        response.Redirect("~/")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
#End Region
```

Comment: Show us the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this error You may be able to specify a data type for the type parameter or parameters instead of relying on type inference.

Comment: The thing is that I have no clue where and what to change - it occurred first in a project that I didn't have any scripts at all in (yet).

Comment: Thanks for assisting! However, I'm too unexperienced to solve this by editing the code. So what I did was removing the projects, and re-creating them from scratch ...